# Are there any dependencies on different INTEL SIMD instruction sets?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, avx

I am currently looking into the SIMD optimization on different CPUs.

For different INTEL SIMD instruction sets, e.g. AVX512, AVX2, AVX, SSE4.1, SSE2, SSE
Are there any dependencies?

By dependency, I mean the following:

(1) For example, if a CPU supports AVX512, does it have to support more basic version AVX or SSE?

(2) If I want to enable optimization for AVX512, does it mean I have to enable AVX or SSE?

If there exists dependency, is there a documentation about this?
I was not able to find the information in "INTEL Intrinsics Guide" https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do all CPUs which support AVX2 also support SSE4.2 and AVX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443249/do-all-cpus-which-support-avx2-also-support-sse4-2-and-avx)

Comment: I'm not aware of Intel officially documenting the fact anywhere, it's just kind of a tacit assumption that all CPU vendors will build incrementally on existing features.  But yes, compilers make that assumption for you, with `-mavx512f` implying AVX1 and 2, and FMA.  (Except for AVX512, where different parts are named, not numbered, like AVX512DQ, so it's somewhat plausible that a new CPU might have some but not other pre-existing AVX-512 things).

Comment: Plus what Mr. Peter Cordes said. There is an unwritten rule. Intel (as well as AMD) cannot remove any instruction from mainstream CPU's once publicly added. Because they care about binary compatibility between generations. Unless of course there is a good opportunity like switching from 32bit to 64bit. Or maybe a long deprecation period like what AMD did (or trying to do).

Comment: Also answer is partially covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215122/which-avx-and-march-should-be-specified-on-a-cluster-with-different-architecture/62224143#62224143

Comment: There is no required dependencies, nor should they be assumed. For any intel related SIMD instruction set, the only 100% certain way to know if it's supported is through calling the CPUID instruction and checking the respective set bits in registers